# Dynamic binding of li tag - Angular5

Tags: angular, html, observable, behaviorsubject

I am trying to implement search func in angular 4 with the dropdowns designed using `<li>`

I make use of a component reference variable - promoList which gets subscribed to a service (which does the string comparison from with the complete list obtained again from a subject's subscription). The service returns the proper output as I have done logging to see that. The component also populates the promoList variable after every subscription but the promoList change is not reflected in the template. Could you help me

Here is my template HTML

```
<div class="searchDiv">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" id="searchSpan" (click)="searchEvent($event)"></span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="search" id="searchInput" class="" list="promotionsSearchList"
            (keyup)="searchEvent($event)" [(ngModel)]="searchModel" />

    <ng-container *ngIf="loadDropDown">
        <ul  class="initialDisplayClass">
            <li *ngFor="let pp of promoList" (click)="selectAnyItem($event)" 
                        class="initialDisplayClass">
                {{pp.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Here is the component (verbiage is shortened)

```
    //import statments goes here
@Component({
    selector: 'app-header',
    templateUrl: './header.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
    textInput: string;
    searchInputArray: string[];
    searchModel: string;
    searchResults : Promotion[];
    // subscribed query param from form control
    queryParam: string;
    loadDropDown: boolean; // initially this value is set as false at the time of loading the screen
    promoList : Promotion[]; 
    subsc: Subscription; 

    constructor(private routeConfig: Router, 
                private searchService: SearchService, 
                private subService: SubjectPromoService,
                private searchFilterService : SearchFilterService, 
                private  activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
                private bufferService: BufferService) {
        this.searchInputArray = new Array<string>();
        this.loadDropDown = false;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.searchFilterService.getQueryParamObservable().subscribe(queryparam => {
            console.log('ngOnit() query param', queryparam);
            this.subService.getSearchResults(queryparam);
        });
    }

    searchEvent(event: Event) {
        // try loading the li after 3 characters are entered

        if (this.searchModel !== undefined && this.searchModel !== null &&  this.searchModel.length > 3){
            this.loadDropDown = true;

            this.searchInputArray.push(this.searchModel);
            console.log('all QUERY PARAMS', 
            this.searchInputArray[this.searchInputArray.length - 1]);
            this.searchFilterService.setQueryParamSubject(this.searchInputArray[this.searchInputArray.length - 1]);
        } else {
            this.loadDropDown = false;
            console.log('setting to empty if length is less than 3');
            this.searchFilterService.setQueryParamSubject('');
        }


        this.searchFilterService.getResultSubjectObservable().subscribe(searchResults => {
                console.log('ngOnit() subscribed result', searchResults);
                this.promoList = searchResults;
                console.log('inside subsc promolist - HEADER', this.promoList);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: is this function `searchEvent` works fine ?

Comment: can you provide code at stackbiz

Comment: Sure, but the code is developed in local using angular cli. Not sure if the dependencies in the stackblitz needs to use all those (since I am new to it) :(

Comment: @Joey587 are you getting the updated list in log when you use `console.log(this. promoList)` ?

Comment: @Anshuman - yes. that is in the component and when used inside the subscription block

Comment: @PranayRana : Everytime I try to run stackblitz , I ending up with an error. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mnw7kt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheader%2Fheader.component.html

Comment: just keep code which is needed not full code

Comment: @PranayRana - here is a sample code. I deleted most part of it. CSS is not getting applied for now (I used bootstrap) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mnw7kt

Comment: @PranayRana -  The search functionality is what I am trying to implement